# How to extract value of DIV tag by a label in JMeter

Tags: html, regex, xml, xpath, jmeter

I'm trying to extract the value of `Document Status` in the sample HTML below using JMeter. In this case the value I want to extract is `Current`.

Is it better to use a regex extractor or an XPath extractor? Can someone please provide the syntax to extract this value?

```
      <div class="spacing--after-s"><div>
      <b>Document status</b>
      <div>  <div class="paragraph">
        <div>
          <b>Status</b>
          <div>Current</div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Definitely XPath. People here will yell at you for using regex on HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//b[.='Status']/following-sibling::div/text()
```

will select the text node child of the `div` element that follows the `b` label whose string value is `'Status'`.

If that label appears elsewhere in your document, let us know and we can refine the XPath to select only the one you want.